# Generalized optimization of the dynamics of one system of equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, euler-lagrange-equation

I am working on Lagrangian derived equations of motions for a robot in matrix form.

Structure of such an equation is known:

$M(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,q)\ddot{q}+C(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,q,\dot{q})\dot{q}+G(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,q)=\tau$

$M(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,q)$, $C(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,q,\dot{q})$ are matrices, and  $G(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,q)$ are vector.

$\ddot{q},\dot{q},q$ and $\tau$ - generalized coordinates and drive forces (all as vectors).

**Problem:** formulate an optimization problem and choose such parameters $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ to minimize (for example) the maximum amount of drive forces.

But, in this case, we are manipulating matrices, and I don't know which functional on the matrix minimizes the effort?

*Trace, norm, their maximum/minimum, their path integral, condition number, etc?*

I asked this question here, but did not get a clear answer: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/22427/equations-of-motion-in-matrix-form-and-energy-consumption

Comment: The movement dynamics are given by

$M(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,q)\ddot{q}+C(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,q,\dot{q})\dot{q}+G(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,q)=\tau$

now given a task to develop, for instance, to follow a path given by $q_r(t)$ from $0\le t\le T$ the problem can be established as an optimal control. So defining 

$$
J(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) = \int_0^T\left(\rho\|\tau\|^2+(q-q_r)'Q(q-q_r)\right)dt
$$

the problem can be stated as

$$
\min_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2}J(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ M(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,q)\ddot{q}+C(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,q,\dot{q})\dot{q}+G(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,q)=\tau
$$

Comment: @Cesareo This is a great idea, but I will note a few not entirely clear points. 1. As far as I can see from $J$, $\tau$ is a control signal? Its equivalent is the classical $u$ used in optimal control. Everything else in the cost function $J$ is classical.

Comment: 2. Next, when we compose the Hamiltonian $H$, we look for the control signal from the equation $\frac{dH}{du}=0$. Such an equation includes the derivative of the norm with respect to the vector $\tau$. Is it possible to get the solution also in vector form?

Comment: 3. Synthesis of co-state equations is obtained through $-\frac{dH}{dq}$. But in all the above procedures, I did not see any manipulations with the $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ parameters, although the optimization problem points to the manipulation with them, as if they were "control signals". But they are not explicitly included in the cost function $J$. Therefore, it is not entirely clear how to work with them.

Comment: Here $\|\tau\|^2 = \tau'\tau$. Making $\theta = (q,\dot q)$ and assuming that $M$ is invertible, we can state an equivalent set of movement equations as $\dot\theta = F(\theta,\tau,\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ and then the hamiltonian

$$
H(\theta,\lambda,\tau,\alpha_1,\alpha_2) = \rho\|\tau\|^2+(\theta-\theta_r)'Q(\theta-\theta_r)+\lambda F(\theta,\tau,\alpha_1,\alpha_2)
$$

Comment: @Cesareo Yes, to write the Hamiltonian, we first need to reduce the 2nd order ODE to the 1st order ODE's system. How to get co-state equations is also clear. With respect to which variables should the Hamiltonian be differentiated in order to obtain control equations? $\frac{dH}{d\tau}$?,$\frac{dH}{d\alpha_1}$?,$\frac{dH}{d\alpha_2}$?

Comment: A generic way to solve this problem is by using a steepests descent procedure over $J(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$. Given $(\alpha_1^k,\alpha_2^k)$ we solve the hamiltonian for $(\theta_k,\tau_k,\lambda_k)$ and then calculate $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \alpha_i^k}$ going to a new iteration now with $(\alpha_1^{k+1},\alpha_2^{k+1})=(\alpha_1^k,\alpha_2^k)-\mu(\frac{\partial J}{\partial \alpha_1^k},\frac{\partial J}{\partial \alpha_2^k})$ with $\mu$ small etc.

Comment: @Cesareo I understand now. The procedure is discrete (iterative). Well, I'll work on the code then, I'll try to get something. Thanks for your help and valuable advice!

Comment: You are welcome.